# Using the z-index

Tags: html, css

I would like to have my "profile-stuff" div to appear over top of my "profile-wrap" div. I tried using z-index, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/HCEN8/

My CSS:

```
#profile-stuff {
padding: 40px 40px 0px 40px;
height: 1000px;
width: 750px;
z-index: 150;
}
```

Comment: z-index requires the container to have some kind of position

Comment: it is not in a container

Comment: It's in a div. Add the `position` to your css for the div containing the content. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066533/using-the-z-index/18066574#answer-18066574) my answer below...

Answer (score 4):

You need to add positioning to the element

```
#profile-stuff {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 40px 0px 40px;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 750px;
    z-index: 150;

}
```

Comment: a note -- doesn't have to be relative positioning... It just needs *SOME* kind of positioning.

Answer (score 1):

In order for z-index to work, you must also have a positioning property.

```
position: relative;
position: absolute;
position: fixed;
```

Comment: Except for the default, `position: static`.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `z-index` to work, your `div` with an id of *profile-stuff* needs to have a `position` property.

Modify your CSS like so:

```
#profile-stuff {
    position: relative;    // <-- Add this property
    padding: 40px 40px 0px 40px;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 750px;
    z-index: 150;
}
```

Add the `position: relative` to your `#profile-stuff` css and it should work fine.

I've modified you're fiddle accordingly. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/HCEN8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The [`z-index` CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/z-index) requires some kind of positioning; add any of the following rules to `#profile-stuff`:

```
position: relative;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
```

or

```
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

The z-index property will only work for elements with their positioning defined. You need to set the 'position' property.

```
#profile-stuff {
    padding: 40px 40px 0px 40px;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 750px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 150;
}
```